# Outlook 2013 - Select specific folder in tree

Tags: vba, outlook

I would like to select a specific in the tree on the left of the Outlook Interface.

I arrived to select folder with this code but I can set focus to the folder.

```
Dim ObjOlFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Set ObjOlFolder = GetNamespace("MAPI").Folders("XXX").Folders("Tools")
Set ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder = ObjOlFolder
```

Thanks By adavance
BR

Comment: "Select" means "highlight/activate" or "allow user to choose" ?

Comment: Hi,"highlight/activate"

Comment: Where and when do you try to run the code?

Comment: In Outlook vba interface

Answer (score 0):

The [CurrentFolder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff866719(v=office.15).aspx) property of the Explorer class allows to set a Folder object that represents the current folder displayed in the explorer. The property is used to change the folder the user is viewing. For example, you may try to run the following VBA code:

```
Sub ChangeCurrentFolder()  
 Dim myNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace 
 Set myNamespace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")  
 Set Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder = _  
 myNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar)  
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks this code select the right folder, but it doesn't set focus to the folder, I need to scrool down to see the folder in the left down outlook interface.
Did you know how I can set Focus ?
Thanks